# extract number from text with comma as separation between them

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i want to extract numbers from text with (,) for ex as separation between the numbers
the dataframe is
[data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhdBx.png)
i use this code

```
WATANIA_MTO['Numbers'] = WATANIA_MTOdf['col'].str.replace('PLATE ','').str.split('X', expand=True)
```

the out put is
[out put](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8eF3k.png)
i want this comma in the end of number column to be between number like this
Numbers
16,80,300
2,80

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
import re
import pandas as pd

df['Numbers'] = df['DES'].apply(lambda x: re.findall(r"[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+", x)).tolist()
df['Numbers'] = df['Numbers'].apply(','.join)
```

##### `>>> display(df)`

[image]